# Creating custom views using view.layout()

Tags: cosmicmind

When creating custom views, I generally create an initialization function by overriding the init(frame) function. When creating the view in my ViewController I initialize the view by passing in the .zero frame, and then set the layout using Material's layout function.

```
let descView = DescriptionView(frame: .zero)
```

However, this makes it so that my views in my custom view are not resized. For example, when setting up a custom text view in my custom view, it does not show up because I prepare it as so:

```
self.layout(descriptionTextView).width(self.width).height(self.height).centerVertically().centerHorizontally()
```

I assume it doesn't show up because when I initialize the view, its width and height are zero. What can I do to get around this?

Comment: What is the look you are trying to go for? Do you know the width and height you are after? Or are you trying to stretch the view?

Comment: I initialize the view with a CGRect of .zero and then use view.layout to resize the view how I want it.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but you are also using values of zero. So you are technically not doing anything incorrectly. It is the values that you are using that are most likely not correct.

Comment: Hmmm...should I be stretching the view using layout then adding the subviews outside of the class?

Comment: I need to see what you want to accomplish, I am not fully understanding what you want to do.

Comment: I want to create a subview which has a textfield that stretches to fit the entire view. My subview's class has a setupTextField() method which stretches the textField to the entire subview's size. However, when I initialize the subview in my view, I initialize it with CGRect.zero, therefore rendering the textView at 0 size.

Comment: So you mentioned a TextField and TextView. Have you seen this sample project that shows how to layout a TextField in multiple ways https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Projects/Programmatic/TextField